# Is `undefined` a type, a value, or both?

Tags: javascript, types, undefined, prototype

1. Is `undefined` a type (data type), a value, or both?
2. Can i use prototype to extend`undefined`

```js
var i;
console.log(i) // => undefined
console.log(typeof i) // => undefined
    
var j = 2;
console.log(j) // => 2
console.log(typeof j) // => number
```

Answer (score 2):

[undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined#Description)

*1. Is undefined a type (data type), a value, or both?*

> `undefined` is a property of the global object; i.e., it is a variable in global scope. The initial value of `undefined` is the primitive value `undefined`.

*2. Can i use prototype to extend undefined?*

> In modern browsers (JavaScript 1.8.5 / Firefox 4+), `undefined` is a non-configurable, non-writable property per the ECMAScript 5 specification. Even when this is not the case, avoid overriding it.